# Printing text from success toast message in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium, I am working on a web application where on clicking "save and next" button a success/warning toast message will be displayed for 5 seconds. I want to print this message. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is the html for the same.

[image]

```
<div class="alert-message animated">
        <alert type="alert.type"><!----> </alert>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: what you tried?what issues you are facing?

Comment: there are multiple alert messages, which one do you want to get?

Comment: Which `print this message`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Raviraja , i have tried switching the window, printing alert, but when i try that it says no such element or no alert

Comment: @Murthi, the one whose div is opened. (which is open)

Comment: @Debanjan , when i click on "Save and Next" , then this toast message displayed as "You are moving to next stage without uploading logo". and that message disappears after 5 secs. i want to print that message which is displayed on toast message.

Comment: Just verify text in 5 second, verify text visibility. If text is visible then print that message.